# Is this a good way to remove spaces from a string in C? note, I am only using the <stdio.h> header file. Also I am new to computer science

Tags: c, char, c-strings, function-definition

```
int remove_whitespace(char* string, int size)   /* input parameters: the character array, size of that array   */
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, num = 0;   /* i - counter variable | j - counter variable | num - number of white spaces */

    for (i; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == ' ')
        {
            for (j = i; j < size - 1; j++)
            {
                string[j] = string[j + 1];
            }
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;   /* returns the number of white spaces */
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see how you're calling that function. See [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We need an objective standard to judge code. Please try [codereview.se] instead, after reading their own how-to-ask material, for questions of code style. Note that *nowhere* on the Stack Exchange network is it appropriate to talk about yourself in the question; talk about *the question*.

Comment: The algorithm is bad.  It runs in O(n^2) time.  A proper algorithm will run in O(n) time.  The problem is that, each time you encounter a space, you copy the entire remainder of the string, including any remaining spaces.  The proper way to do it is to have two indices (or two pointers) into the string, copying from one to the other and skipping spaces are you encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

Count the 5 variables used by the function presented. Five! Are they all being incremented correctly? A pair of nested for() loops and an if() conditional. Are the indexes the correct index for the purpose??

Depending on the parameters passed, will whitespace be compacted but leave trailing characters in the array? Is this why the caller receives the "shrinkage" quantity?

Your title suggests "string", yet the code presented indicates an array of characters (without consideration for a C string terminating '\0'.) Taking the approach that you want to remove SP's (0x20) from a null terminated C string, the following will do that:

```
void stripSP( char *s ) {
    for( char *d = s; (*d = *s) != '\0'; s++ ) d += *d != ' ';
}
```

One line of code utilising two pointers.

You could pass/use a second parameter that is the character to be expunged, 
or change the `d += *d != ' ';` to `d += !isspace(*d);` to compact-out any whitespace characters (incl. '\t', '\r' & '\n').

Obviously, this leads to possibilities of stripping out punctuation, or whatever you'd like removed. If the caller needs to know the new length of the string, the caller can invoke `strlen()`.

It's one little line of source code, amenable to customising to suit your needs. For instance, the function *could* preserve and return the start address for *chaining* function calls.

Answer (score -1):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
size_t remove_char( char *string, size_t size, char c );
```

That is you should not write a separate function if you will want to remove another character instead of the space character `' '`. Always try to write more general functions.

Also the function should return the size of the character array without the removed character.

Using nested for loops when all characters after the removed character are moved to the left is inefficient.

The function can be defined the following way

```
size_t remove_char( char *string, size_t size, char c )
{
    size_t n = 0;
 
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        if ( string[i] != c )
        {
            if ( n != i ) string[n] = string[i];
            ++n;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t remove_char( char *string, size_t size, char c )
{
    size_t n = 0;
 
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        if ( string[i] != c )
        {
            if ( n != i ) string[n] = string[i];
            ++n;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[10] = "H e l l o";

    size_t n = remove_char( s, sizeof( s ), ' ' ); 

    printf( "%zu: %s\n", n - 1, s );
}
```

The program output is

```
5: Hello
```

If you want to remove a character from a string then the function can be declared like

```
char * remove_char( char *string, char c );
```

because you can determine the length of a string within the function by founding the terminating zero character '\0'.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * remove_whitespace( char* string, char c )
{
    if ( *string )
    {
        char *dsn = string, *src = string;

        do
        {
            if ( *src != c )
            {
                if ( dsn != src ) *dsn = *src;
                ++dsn;
            }
        } while ( *src++ );
    }

    return string;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[10] = "H e l l o";

    puts( remove_whitespace( s, ' ' ) ); 
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
```